# Is there a city in the world with more bridges than Amsterdam, the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, where-on-earth, factoids, cities

I know there are cities with bigger bridges and with more famous bridges.
But are there cities with more?
[According to this site](http://amsterdamfaq.com/1/amsterdam) Amsterdam has 1,753 bridges with a number and more without.

> HOW MANY BRIDGES DOES AMSTERDAM HAVE?
>
> 1,753 — many of which can open to let ships pass. ‘The bridge was open’ is a popular excuse for arriving late at school or work (regardless of whether your route actually includes a bridge…). 80 of these bridges are within the famous ‘grachtengordel’ (‘belt of canals). There are an additional 2250+ so-called ‘non-numbered’ bridges — most of them far less significant than the numbered ones.

This [site has links to (almost all) bridges in](http://www.bruggenvanamsterdam.nl/) Amsterdam. I have not checked out all, but the numbered bridges up to #2484 either indicate they are over water by the name of the location and/or by the picture. Not all with proper roads but all possible to walk or drive over.
Besides those 2484 there are 'other bridges' which are either not over water, not having roads on them or may not fit my rules for other reasons.
Although some still fit and are not numbered for reasons I do not know.
As a bridge I count where a road crosses over water, not where a road crosses over an other road or railway nor where a railway crosses over anything.

If there is a city with more bridges I would be interested in visiting it.
And if there is no city with more bridges, I would like to know the ones with almost as many bridges.

[image: bridge over the Prinsengracht by Westertoren, Amsterdam]
*Bridge over the Prinsengracht by Westertoren, Amsterdam*
Photo by Willeke, can be used freely.

Comment: Next you should ask about density; Amsterdam has only about 3/10ths the surface area of Hamburg.

Comment: I am surprised by the Hamburg answer, I was thinking it would be on an other continent at least.

Comment: Are you an ogre? Is that why you like bridges? :P

Comment: Only 409 in Venice, to pick an obvious city.

Comment: @JoErNano are you getting your mythology mixed up, or are you [trolling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Billy_Goats_Gruff)?

Answer (score 12):

Depending on your definition of the word "bridge", [Hamburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg) definitely comes on top with [2496 bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bridges_in_Hamburg).

[image]

Comment: Not sure Hamburg's bridges qualify now I limited to bridges of road over water.

Comment: @Willeke I don't think Amsterdam's 1753 bridges are all road over water either.

Comment: From that second site I found, 2500 or more of the bridges in the Amsterdam area are over water. Each comes with photos, so you can check.

Comment: @Willeke the answer is then "no, there are no cities with a larger number of bridges"?

Comment: @JonathanReez: Why did you answer this question rather than closevote it? Is number of bridges more travelly than [number of nesting levels of Autonomous regions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79312/)? Perhaps you like visiting bridges but do not like visiting Chinese ethnic minorities? I'm struggling to come up with any qualitative difference on travel grounds.

Comment: @hippietrail 'an autonomy within an autonomy' is just a geopolitical naming quirk and there could be many of them. A 'city with the most bridges' is a travel sight on its own and there is only one by definition.

Comment: It's not a naming quirk at all. Apparently you make decisions based on things you don't know about. Chinese autonomous areas are based on their significant ethnic minority populations. Anyone interested in visiting minority peoples is interested in such things. The Kazakhs are a minority in China. The fact that the much smaller minority of Xibe, who are the last relatives of the Manchu still maintaining their old language exist only within a Kazakh area, are also a minority, is very interesting. And the fact that they are all within an area which is recognized as culturally Uyghur is amazing!

Comment: But yeah who cares about that stuff when there's a city which a good number of nice bridges and a very high number of totally uninteresting bridges.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. voting to reopen.